# Tilde not working on Ubuntu I installed on Windows 11

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 11 and I've been trying to use Tilde on the terminal, but it keeps giving me an error. `cd ../Pictures` takes me to the `Pictures` directory, but `cd ~/Pictures` says:

```
No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Wht's the output of `echo ~`?

Comment: `~` alone is first expanded to the `HOME` shell variable in bash if it’s set … Alternatively specifying a user like `~user` will expand to the specified user’s home instead … So, you might want to try that explicitly with your user.

Answer (score 3):

When you start the bash shell in WSL, e.g. using the Windows "Terminal" product, the initial working directory **may** not be the same as the Linux (Ubuntu) home directory.

You can check this by typing `pwd`. It will show something like

```
/mnt/c/Users/<windowsusername>/
```

which is the Windows users' directory and `ls -l` will show a `Pictures/` directory.

You can change to the home dir of the Linux user with:
`cd ~`, `cd "${HOME}"` or just `cd`.

Type `pwd` again and you will see `/home/<linuxusername>`.

There is no `Pictures/` directory there, check with `ls -l`.

Comment: of course it's Windows ... What else could be wrong? ;-)

Comment: @Raffa: Thanks for the enhancements of my answer !